# Redirect to edit after twitter signin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using twitter omniauth to allow users to sign in with twitter. Since twitter doesn't share the users email, I want to redirect them to info_path after they sign in for the first time (when email is blank). Info_path is just a custom devise edit page that acts as a second login page. The problem is I am unable to get it to redirect to the info page if their email is blank.

This is my omniauth_callbacks controller:

```
def all
  user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if user.persisted? and user.email.present?
    sign_in_and_redirect user
  elsif user.persisted? and user.email.blank?
    sign_in user and redirect_to info_path
  else
    session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
    redirect_to new_user_registration_url
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "unable"? What happens? An error? Can you be more descriptive, please?

Comment: It just redirects to the homepage instead of the info page.

Comment: It does because the first `if` statement is being satisfied. Right? So there is an email. What happens when you try with a new user that has no email?

Comment: Oops, stupid me, that was it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix. I was using an account i assumed had no email but did. Thanks @Mohamad.